# Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: javascript, xml

I've been searching around for answers to this particular problem for about two days now. I can't seem to figure out what's going on with it. All this seemed to have worked in the past but isn't working anymore.

XML:

```
<ZipCodes>
<results>
    <city>Chicago</city>
    <state>IL</state>
    <timezone>-6</timezone>
</results>
```

javascript:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","_checkzip.php?zip="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("results");
i=0;



    document.forms["signup"]["City"].value=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("city")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.forms["signup"]["states"].value=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("state")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.forms["signup"]["TimeZone"].value=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("timezone")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

and the error I get is

```
Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

when I try x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("results");  The xml is deffinetly coming in on the network response when I look at the debug in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an event handler on an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)'s `onreadystatechange` to make sure the request is done. If the status of readyState is 4, the operation is complete.

Currently you're asking for data that hasn't been transmitted yet.

Comment: I'm using      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
            x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ZipCodes");

        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","_checkzip.php?zip="+str,false);
        xmlhttp.send();  But getting the same thing with Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null on ZipCodes. If I use alert(xmlhttp.responseText) instead of responseXML, I'm still able to see all of the XML.

Comment: If your server doesn't send back data with the text/xml content-type, your  browser won't recognize the XML, and won't parse it as an XML document. You can try checking that, or if you're certain it should be XML, you can override the mimetype using [overrideMimetype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#overrideMimeType())('text/xml') to enfore the XML parsing.

Comment: Nailed it. That was it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from ensuring that xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200, this error can also occur if you outputed any content, letter, character or string before sending your xml data from the server. For instance Assuming that in java  you have a method/function called sendXMLdata, and then in your servlet you printed the string "connected" before calling the method:
....
    out.println("Connected");
    String data="My Name"
    sendXMLdata(response,data);
....

Then the output when viewed from browser source will be this:
Connected
My Name

So this will certainly give you an error since the browser would not be able to parse the string "connected" since it is not the write format to render xml data.